# Writing generic Monoid over Cofree; undecidable?

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass, undecidable-instances

I'm trying to write the following Monoid instance for Cofree:

```
instance (Monoid a, Monoid (f (Cofree f a))) => Monoid (Cofree f a) where
  mempty = mempty :< mempty
  (a :< rest) `mappend` (b :< rest') = (a `mappend` b) :< (rest `mappend` rest')
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
• Variable ‘f’ occurs more often
    in the constraint ‘Monoid (f (Cofree f a))’
    than in the instance head
  (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
• In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Cofree f a)’
```

I've come across Undecidable Instances before, but I'm not really sure WHY this is undecidable, and how can I fix it? Do I need to add UndecidableInstances? Thanks!!

Comment: `UndecidableInstances` means that GHC could diverge (as in give up with an less helpful message) while trying to type check your code. The particular problem is that `Monoid (f (Cofree f a))` could, for example, require `Monoid (Cofree f a)`, so just checking that instance might loop forever.

Comment: `UndeciableInstances` doesn't even mean that the compiler thinks that instance resolution *could* diverge; it means the compiler can't prove it *won't* diverge. This use case is probably pretty safe.

Comment: What difference between those two things are you trying to point out, @user2407038? If the compiler can't prove it won't diverge, then the compiler thinks it could diverge. They sound the same to me.

Comment: Feel free to reopen is you feel the duplicate doesn't answer enough. "Do I need to add UndecidableInstances?": Yes, add `{-# LANGUAGES UndecidableInstances #-}` to the top of your file - it should be ok here.